# $_item->getOptionByCode('simple_product') in Order Mail

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, email, email-templates

In the checkout-cart `(template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml)` I have this code:

```
$simpleProduct = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct();
```

I want to use the same code in the Order Mail `(template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml)`

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
...
$simpleProduct = $_item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct();
```

This leads to this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object
```

So how can I get the simple_product of configurable product in mail order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nbar, Please use `sku` field of order item. In Magento if you `ordered a configurable product` then Magento is save `configurable  product's`  `child` simple `product sku` has saved in DB.

You need to load simple product by this sku

```
$simplePro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadbyAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue. You need to load a `quote_item` object which is where that method (`getOptionByCode()`) is defined.

Here's one way of doing this; probably not the most efficient, but it works:

```
<?php 

// template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

$_item    = $this->getItem();
$_order   = $this->getItem()->getOrder();

// Get quote data
$quoteId      = $_order->getQuoteId();
$quote        = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$quoteItemId  = $_item->getQuoteItemId();

// Load quote items
$quoteItemCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_collection');
$quoteItemCollection->setQuote($quote);

// Loop through quote items and identify the current one
// You can maybe do this above somehow using a filter method
foreach ($quoteItemCollection->getItems() as $quoteItem) {

    // Current item is the target (top-level scope) item?
    if ($quoteItem->getId() == $quoteItemId) {

        $itemProduct = $quoteItem->getProduct();

        // Here's the getOptionByCode line
        if ($itemProduct->isConfigurable() && $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
            // Party
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
$simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
foreach($simpleCollection as $simpleProduct){
    echo "name:".$simpleProduct->getName();
    echo "<br>";
    echo "price:".$simpleProduct->getPrice();
    echo "<br>";
}
```